# Spring - how to make custom bean values for different consumers

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using spring and I want to somehow customize one of dependencies so it will depend on what class is requesting this bean.

For example, I have have some interface Logger and two consumers

```
class A {
    @Inject Logger logger;
}
class B {
    @Inject Logger logger;
}
```

How can I create @Configuration that supplies different instances of Logger to A and B? I can not specify it in A or B bean declaration, as logger should know what bean is is used for.

In fact I want something like

```
@Configuration class Config {
    @Bean
    Logger loggerFor(Class consumer) {
        return new Logger(consumer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that Storage is an interface so I think this will do it:

```
@Autowired
@Resource(name = "yourImplementation")
private Storage storage;
```

The resource annotation is at javax.annotation.Resource

Comment: Sorry, I corrected question. I meant I need to use different instances of same implementation for different consumers

Comment: Oh, in that case I think what you need is to use the component with a "prototype" scope. This is a link for the scopes available http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: Thanks, I've added @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) to Bean factory method definition. This method is invoked for every consumer bean, but how do I know for which one?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do that using pure spring configuration, but in this case you can do something like this:
if (consumer instanceof A) new LoggerA() else new LoggerB()
Not very pretty though.

Comment: I mean, how would I know who is the consumer in factory method? I have some @Bean @Scope(...) public Logger logger() method, what parameter type should I add to logger() method to identify consumer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. In your case, maybe it would be a good idea to create a service like LoggingService with methods like service.log(Consumer.class) and inside it you create a new Logger and log it. Then all you have to do is inject the service into the classes you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different Beans for Storage Object and inject with there reference.

```
<bean id="b" class="B">
    <property name="storage" ref="storageA" />
</bean>

<bean id="storageA" class="Storage" />
<bean id="storageB" class="Storage" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected question. I meant I need to use different instances of same implementation for different consumers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question completely, but here are a couple of approaches for autowiring in dependencies where you need to disambiguate based on some characteristic of the bean:

.1. Autowiring by name:

```
class A {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("loggerForClassA") Logger logger;
}
class B {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("loggerForClassB") Logger logger;
}

@Configuration class Config {
    @Bean
    Logger loggerForClassA() {
        return new Logger(A.class);
    }
    @Bean
    Logger loggerForClassB() {
        return new Logger(B.class);
    }

}
```

.2. Autowiring by generic type
If your logger is a generic type, then you can actually disambiguate by the parameterized type at runtime, like this:

```
class A {
    @Autowired Logger<A> logger;
}
class B {
    @Autowired Logger<B> logger;
}

@Configuration class Config {
    @Bean
    Logger<A> loggerForClassA() {
        return new Logger(A.class);
    }
    @Bean
    Logger<B> loggerForClassB() {
        return new Logger(B.class);
    }
}
```